# Описания приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Такой вопрос, приложение на английского языке, описание приложения в `android developer console` на английском языке. Когда человек заходит с телефона, где русский основной язык, то в `Google Play` показывается корявый машинный перевод описания этого приложения. Можно как-то вообще запретить переводить описание приложения на локальные языки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо просто создать собственный перевод в консоли разработчика и в него копирнуть английский текст. Так должен будет ваш англ. текст отображаться для всех локалей, для которых вы это сделаете.